# Visual studio auto-indent for variable assignments

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I know VS could do that, but i can't remember the operation name nor the shortcut for it...

Visual studio does the following:

Before:

```
string a = "bliblablubb";
string ab = "bliblablubb";
string abc = "bliblablubb";
string abcd = "bliblablubb";
```

After:

```
string a    = "bliblablubb";
string ab   = "bliblablubb";
string abc  = "bliblablubb";
string abcd = "bliblablubb";
```

I am currently using VS2013 preview.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can install the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) extension and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> (see the `Align Assignments` section on that page). (Edit - doesn't seem to support VS2013 preview but I'll leave it here for others who are using 2010/[2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd)).

Alternatively, you could try using the [Code alignment](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7179e851-a263-44b7-a177-1d31e33c84fd) extension. This claims to support VS2013.

Both options require a non-express edition of Visual Studio as express editions don't support extensions.

Comment: Will it even install on OP's 2013?  I'm using VS 2012 and it won't install saying it only works for 2010.

Comment: Here:  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd

Comment: Are the Power tools even available for VS2013?

Comment: I doubt it, since it's preview.

Comment: I haven't tried the Power Tools on  2013 but the Code alignment extension says 2013 is supported.

Comment: do not forget to tell IDE to leave such formatting alone! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834688/stop-visual-studio-2013-from-automatically-removing-extra-spaces-in-assignments

Comment: Both Productivity Power Tools and Code alignment extensions seem to be dead - they have not been updated in 5+ years. I was hoping for a native way to align code via `.editorconfig` but I cannot find this feature. Maybe there is a Roslyn Analyzer that provides a code fix to achieve this kind of formatting?

Answer (score 4):

I use productivity tools, they provide the following shortcut (Ctrl+Al+ special character) because I'm using spanish layout the character I see is ¡, but for example in german is ´ ... so better you install the extension and you will see the one that works for your 
[image: example]

Hope it helps.

Bye.

Comment: how did you do that for VS2013? as far as i know it only works for 2012

Comment: @Nefarion Why did you accept the answer, if it doesn't work for you?

Comment: You are right, it may be right for VS2012 but i can't use it, and it might lead others to a wrong conclusion if they read the question and answer poorly...

Comment: @Nefarion Well, you can always re-accept this answer as soon as the productivity tools support VS2013. As it stands now, it deserves a +1 but not an accept (not yet) ;)

Comment: productivity tools are now supported in VS2013 ;)

Answer (score -5):

Shortcut for format document Ctrl + K,D