# Stop Visual Studio 2013 from automatically removing extra spaces in assignments

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, code-formatting

I'm trying to align some assignments to improve readability, but each time I paste something, Visual Studio 2013 automatically removes the extra spaces before the `=`.

For example, this:

```
static class Constants {
    public static string Something      = "A value";
    public static string SomethingElse  = "Another value";
}
```

gets re-formatted like this:

```
static class Constants {
    public static string Something = "A value";
    public static string SomethingElse = "Another value";
}
```

Is there a way to turn this off?

Comment: I'm not sure the feature, but you can press ctrl+z immediately after pasting to get the original formatting back.

Comment: @Matthew: yes, I know, but it's quite annoying to have to undo every time... moreover, I would still like to be able to format the document (`ctrl-k`, `ctrl-d`) without all alignments exploding :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be turned off in `Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Formatting->Spacing` via the "Ignore spaces in declaration statements" option.

[image]

Comment: No problem :-) Seems there's only an option for declarations though, not assignments in general. Ah well.

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to have some more "ignore" options.

Comment: While this should work, it does not appear to have the desired effect as Format Document still removes extra blanks and tabs

Answer (score 3):

```
VB.net for VisualStudio 2016 instructions:

|<-- main menu bar -->|<------------Side Panel Of Options Window------>|
Tools --> Options --> | Text Editor v | --> | Basic v | --> | Advanced |

    Options.Advanced window:
 =========================================================  
 =   +----Highlighting-------------------------------+   =
 =   | (...)                                         |   =
 =   +-----------------------------------------------+   =
 =                                                       =
 =   +----Outlining----------------------------------+   =
 =   | (...)                                         |   =
 =   +-----------------------------------------------+   =
 =                                                       =
 =   +----Editor Help--------------------------------+   =
 =   |                                               |   =
 =   | [ ] Pretty listing (reformatting) of code     |   =
 =   |                                               |   =
 =   +-----------------------------------------------+   =
 =========================================================
```

Screen shot:
[image]